# getUpdateCount returns total number of rows updates for Oracle, but returns -1 in PostgreSQL and SQL Server, and latest count in H2

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying batch update and then get total number of rows affected. For Oracle I get correct output by using getUpdateCount, but this API fails for PostgreSQL, SQL Server and H2. For these databases I need to iterate and add executeBatch output.

```java
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(getSQL());
//created queries via addBatch()
int[] ints = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
int updateCount = preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
Assert.assertEquals(updateCount,3);
Assert.assertNotNull(ints);
```

I am curious why this API does not give correct output? My drivers are as follows.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Because you're using it wrong. you should use the array that is returned from the batch. getUpdateCount must be checked against -1 etc. Read the docs

Comment: @siggemannen then why am I getting correct result for oracle? Shouldn't API work same across all drivers?

Comment: Because databases are different. sql server generates resultsets containing updatecounts (unless you do set nocount on). oracle probably don't. But if you use the API correctly, ie. check for -1, use nextresultset etc, then it will work exactly the same. But it could also be bugs in the drivers, so your mileage may vary :) Plus, as i said, you should be using the array when working with batches anyway

Comment: `net.sourceforge.jtds` hasn't had a release since 2013. Are you expecting that to work correctly against modern SQL Servers and modern versions of the TDS protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `executeBatch`, you shouldn't check `getUpdateCount()` **at all**, you should look at the returned array **only**. The behaviour for `getUpdateCount()` is only specified in combination with `execute()` and `getMoreResults()`. Its behaviour is **unspecified** by JDBC for any other method of execution, so you cannot rely on any specific behaviour (i.e. it is driver-specific) if you didn't call `execute()` or `getMoreResults()` (which you can by specification only call after you've used `execute()`).

Specifically, the [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-spec/index.html) only covers `getUpdateCount()` in section *13.1.2.3 Returning Unknown or Multiple Results*, which describes the use of `execute`, `getMoreResults` and `getUpdateCount()` and `getResultSet()`, and ties the behaviour of those methods specifically to `execute`.

That said, with singular execution using `executeQuery()` and `executeUpdate()` most drivers will usually be pretty consistent as if `execute()` had been used (though you cannot rely on this!), but with `executeBatch()` it will highly depend on how the batch execution is implemented and how update counts are retrieved.

For example, if the driver emulates batch support by executing the parameter sets individually, it is highly likely that `getUpdateCount()` returns the last update count (probably by accident of implementation of the normal execution), while if the DBMS supports server-side batch execution, it is unlikely that you get an update count other than `-1`, because it would require implementing explicitly summing the update counts of the individual parameter sets, unless maybe the DBMS also reports the total update count of the entire batch in some way.

In short, the behaviours you have observed for Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server and H2 are **all correct**, because it is **unspecified** by JDBC.